# Does scalar curvature is bounded by absolute value of Riemann curvature?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

Is it true if the lowest eigenvalue of the Ricci tensor is negative than $Scal \le |Rm|$?

What i guess is $$|Rm| \ge \frac{Scal}{n} $$ by using Cauchy-schwarz inequality. However while i read the article about partial flow on 3D, i saw (i might be wrong) they use the first inequality which does not contain n.

Comment: The relevant formula is the Ricci decomposition described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_decomposition. Since the 3 components are orthogonal, $$ |\mathrm{Rm}|^2 = |W|^2 + |E|^2 + |S|^2  \ge |S|^2,$$ where $S$ is the $4$-tensor defined there in terms of the scalar curvature (denoted $R$ there). It remains to calculate $|S|^2$ in terms of the scalar curvature. I tried this and got a constant slightly better than yours but not as good as $1$.

Comment: @Deane Thanks. I learned there is a better constant for inequality. However, the fact that the constant is not 1 makes me frustrated. I was sure that they use constant 1. Anyway thanks again.